# TaskCompletionSource to represent Async

Tags: asynchronous

Sorry my knowledge with threads is still a bit weak.

Just reading around. If you use TaskCompletionSource to represent some IO Async operation.

Like say some DownloadAsync, you are not tying up a thread as I understand?

I always thought when something is happening asynchronously it must be tying up a thread?

Any clarification is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The DownloadFileAsync of the webclient provides a good opportunity to apply TPL in a Event based asynchronous model.
Since the action that includes the call to the DownloadFileAsync completes quickly, the real work isn't done until the DownloadFileCompleted event is triggered. This is where the TaskCompletionSource comes into play.

```
   var downloadCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted+=
                (s, e) =>
                    {
                         if (e.Error != null)
                           {
                                downloadCompletionSource.SetException(e.Error);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                downloadCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
                            }
                        }

                    };

          webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), destinationFilePath);

            try
            {
                downloadCompletionSource.Task.Wait();

            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {

            }
```

More can be found here [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454.aspx)